# JIRA: How to add a separator to a menu plugin between two links

Tags: jira

I do my first steps in creating a plugin with the [Atlassian Plugin SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/DOCS/Getting+Started) and I tried the [Adding Menu Items to JIRA](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Adding+Menu+Items+to+JIRA) tutorial.

Now, I would like to add a separator between two menu links (like it is in the dashboard menu) but I did not find a hint how to do it.

I took a look at the [Web Item Plugin Module](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Web+Item+Plugin+Module) but cannot find anything helpful.

Is there anybody with a tip for me - this can't be to complicated and I am for sure just blind...

In advance, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `web-section` is used to group menu items together, including adding a label above a group of collected menu options...and it also forces a line above the section. If you do not specify a label, it will simply render as a line, which is what you want.

The `web-item`s that you want to go below the line should have a `location` set to "inside" the web-section you create, which you construct by setting the location to whatever your original menu location was, a slash, and the key you used for the new web section.

eg.

```xml
<web-item key="myMenuItemBeforeTheLine" ... location="YOUR_ORIGINAL_MENU_LOCATION">
   ... menu option goes here ...
</web-item>

<web-section key="NEW_SECTION" ... location="YOUR_ORIGINAL_MENU_LOCATION">
   ...
</web-section>

<web-item key="myMenuItemAfterTheLine" ... location="YOUR_ORIGINAL_MENU_LOCATION/NEW_SECTION">
   ... menu options goes here ...
</web-item>
```